# Matlab read specified lines and create a structure

Tags: string, matlab, io

Suppose we have a txt file containing the following data (`output.txt`):

```
MC Sim:
x1 =  28.87      x2 =  28.87     x3 =  24.02 
C = 51   Iter = 1    S =   3.00     M=  26.77 
C = 51   Iter = 2    S =   7.85     M=  32.70 
C = 51   Iter = 3    S =  18.62     M=  46.85 

MC Sim:
x1 =  28.87      x2 =  28.87     x3 =  19.65 
C = 51   Iter= 1     S =   3.00     M =  22.28 
C = 51   Iter= 2     S =   3.77     M =  25.10 
C = 51   Iter= 3     S =   4.99     M =  28.89 
C = 51   Iter= 4     S =   8.40     M =  35.78 
C = 51   Iter= 5     S =  12.13     M =  46.22 
C = 51   Iter= 6     S =  27.95     M =  72.74
```

I would like to read some lines and create a specified strucure from the values it contains, ***automatically***. For example, suppose we want to a create the following structure using the values of **S** & **M** between lines 3 and 5:

```
Iter1.S = the value of S at line 3 (3.00)
Iter1.M = the value of M at line 3 (26.77)

Iter2.S = the value of S at line 4 (7.85)
Iter2.M = the value of M at line 4 (32.70)

Iter3.S = the value of S at line 5 (18.62)
Iter3.M = the value of M at line 5 (46.85)
```

Please pay attention the name of each field should be a concatenated string containing the variable name **Iter** and its value, e.g. `Iter1 = Iter+1` .

Comment: Please pay attention! It is not recommended in MATLAB to use root variable names composed of iterative numbers, specially if these variables have to be contructed automatically (at runtime). Instead, since you are already using `structure` elements, use their [dynamic field name](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) capability.